# Get published posts and pages?

Tags: wpdb

I'm working on a plugin to use gettext in posts and pages content.

I'm trying to get all published posts and pages in order scan them for translatable strings, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

This is what I'm trying:

```
$pages = $wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = "publish"');
foreach ( $pages as $post ) {
    print_r($post);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use pure SQL if you don't have to. WordPress provides a useful and relatively solid class for retrieving post data. Use it.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('post','page'),
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);
// Show post titles
foreach ($qry->posts as $p) { 
    echo $p->post_title; 
}
```

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: how can I echo each post title and post? I'm trying to do this `foreach ($result->post as $post) { echo $post->post_title; }` and reading the docs but I cannot figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro : see the edit.

Comment: I just added a new question that steams from this one, you can check it here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137474/select-posts-with-any-post-type-from-database

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'"));

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    print_r($post);
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?