# Select posts with any post_type from database?

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to select all rows from the database regardless of post type, however when suppressing post_type WP_Query only gets rows with `post_type = "post"` is there a way to suppress the post_type filter (or select all post types)?

```
// This just selects post_type = "posts"
$args = array(
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);
$qry = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

By default-- that is, unlss told otherwise-- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) will search the `post` post type. You may supply [`'post_type' => 'any'`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2215) to retrieve all post types, but be aware that things like attachments are post types. For example...

```
$args = array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'post_type' => 'any'
);
$qry = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($qry->request);
```

Post types set as [not searchable](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2677), such as the menu post type (which has no business being a post type at all IMHO), will be ignored. If you need those odd-ball post types, you will need to list them. [`get_post_types()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) should help with that.

```
$args = array(
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
   'post_type' => get_post_types(),
);
$qry = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I've been making some tests and it seems that this is not the same as `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'`. Some post types like nav_menu_item are not being selected. Any ideas how to include them?

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro : see the edit.